how to prove well-ordering isomorphic theorem?
I am reading well-ordering isomorphism theorem in Kunen's "set theory : an intro function to independence proofs(1980)"

here, "pred" refers to initial segment for an element x in A under relation R.
at first glance, if we define f in the above way, it seems that if A's cardinal less than B, then (b) will be satisfied and at converse case
also will be clear.

but I don't understand how the mere fact that A, B are well-ordered guarantees the fact that we can define well-order isomorphism from pred(A, x, R) to pred(B, w, S) in definition of f?

even if the question in (1) is clear, how can the function f be extend to fact (b) or (c) when it is only partially confirmed that the domain and range at pred(A, x, R) and pred(B, w, S) are well-ordering isomorphism?



There is no room for cardinality to have a role in this proof. Do you mean the ordertype or something else?

Regarding 1, the definition of $f$ only cares the existence of an isomorphism. It does not care how we can construct it. Also, you can see that the only order isomorphism between a well-order $\alpha$ to itself is the identity, which implies the uniqueness of the isomorphism between two well-orders if exists.
